# How to export test results in xunit(internal template of asp.net core) using cake script?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using **VS 2017 professional (version 15.2)** with platform of **Asp.net core (version 1.1)**. I am using a testing framework of **Xunit (which is in the internal template of asp.net core)**. I try to use the cake script for running the test cases written in Xunit using the cake script, I need to export test results like passed and failed test case count.

```
Task("Test").Does(() =>
   {
      var settings = new DotNetCoreTestSettings
       {
         Configuration = "Release"
       };

     var projectFiles = GetFiles("./test/**/*.csproj");

     foreach(var file in projectFiles)
      {
        DotNetCoreTest(file.FullPath, settings);
      }
  });
```

When I run this code in cake test execution should be finished but I need detailed test results.

Can anyone please suggest how to export the results of test cases?

Answer (score 2):

This will output test results in MSTest `.trx` format to a 'TestResults' folder in each project folder:

```
var settings = new DotNetCoreTestSettings
{
  Configuration = "Release",
  ArgumentCustomization = args => args.Append("-l trx")
};
```